How to test write to a file with functions Write, WriteAt and Truncate in Go
I'd like to test a function in Golang that write to a file using three different methods:  Write, WriteAt and Truncate. The method I know is to use buffer, but buffer's method Truncate is diferent from file method.
This is the code that write to a file using three functions: Write, WriteAt and Truncate
package main

import (
    "io"
    "os"
)

type Truncater interface {
    Truncate(size int64) error
}

type WriterFull interface {
    io.Writer
    io.WriterAt
    Truncater
}

func main() {

    fileName := "myFile"
    file, _ := os.Create(fileName)
    defer file.Close()

    WriteToTheFile(file)

}

func WriteToTheFile(file WriterFull) {

    file.Write([]byte("Ny text full of words"))
    file.WriteAt([]byte("M"), 0)
    file.Truncate(6)

}


Accordingly to this source, I need bytes.Buffer to test my function WriteToTheFile(file WriterFull), the *_test.go file
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "testing"
)

func TestWriteToTheFile(t *testing.T) {
    var buffer bytes.Buffer
    buffer.WriteString("Not my text")
    WriteToTheFile(&buffer)
}

I get the error
cannot use &buffer (value of type *bytes.Buffer) as WriterFull value in argument to WriteToTheFile: *bytes.Buffer does not implement WriterFull (wrong type for method Truncate)
        have Truncate(int)
        want Truncate(int64) errorcompilerInvalidIfaceAssign

As far as I know, it is not possible to create an interface with two equaly named functions, and file and buffer are incompatible, while the first use Truncate(int64) the second use have Truncate(int).
How to properly perform tests in a function that use the three functions from a var file Write, WriteAt and Truncate?

If you want to test a function that write a file: Call that function an verify the file file was written properly. Trying to abstract away writing to the file system is complete nonsense in almost all cases. A sensible place to write these files is into the ./testdata folder. The problem seems to be that you do not really know what exactly your "test" should demonstrate or guard against: Is it writing to the FS and proper error handling and cleanup? Is it calling the appropriate os functions? Depending on that you design your tests.

My app reads a file, process the data, and writes to two other files in a very specific way. I want to test if the data is correct among all files, not the os io functionality of open/write to a file. Your solution works and I will consider it as last option, thanks, but is inelegant and is a workaround.

If you want to test special interactions with files, using an in-memory filesystem seems beneficial:
package main

import (
    "testing"

    "github.com/spf13/afero"
)

func TestWriteToTheFile(t *testing.T) {
    t.Parallel()

    testFs := afero.NewMemMapFs()

    file, _ := afero.TempFile(testFs, "/", "*")
    fileName := file.Name()

    _, _ = file.WriteString("Not my text")
    WriteToTheFile(file)

    file.Close()

    got, _ := afero.ReadFile(testFs, fileName)
    expected := "Mot my"
    if string(got) != expected {
        t.Errorf("Got: %q, expected: %q", string(got), expected)
    }
}

There are other implementations of in-memory file systems, this is just an example.
Note that you should add error handling to the test and your code.
Also, as @Volker correctly remarks, it might be worthwhile to use a real file system for testing (Go Playground):
package main

import (
    "os"
    "testing"
)

func TestWriteToTheFile(t *testing.T) {
    t.Parallel()

    file, _ := os.CreateTemp("", "*")
    fileName := file.Name()
    defer os.Remove(fileName)

    _, _ = file.WriteString("Not my text")
    WriteToTheFile(file)

    file.Close()

    got, _ := os.ReadFile(fileName)
    expected := "Mot my"
    if string(got) != expected {
        t.Errorf("Got: %q, expected: %q", string(got), expected)
    }
}

